# Cannot check if my variable is nil or not SWIFT

Tags: ios, swift, release, option-type

I have a very strange issue.
I need to check if my Binary Data (in my coredata base) is nil or not.

In the console, if I print directly the variable, it's nil.
But if I use if/else condition to check it, my variable is not nil.

```
println(self.selectedPost!.attachment?.image) // ->print nil 

if let mybinary = self.selectedPost!.attachment?.image {    
    println("mybinary is not nil") // -> print "mybinary is not nil"
} else {
    println("mybinary is nil")
}
```

EDIT

Same result using :

```
if self.selectedPost!.attachment?.image != nil {...
    println("mybinary is not nil") // -> print "mybinary is not nil"
} else {
    println("mybinary is nil")
}
```

I don't understand why.

This issue appears only in release mode not in debug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could also try to us `as?` to cast the data in your if statement.

```
println(self.selectedPost!.attachment?.image) // ->print nil 

if let mybinary = self.selectedPost!.attachment?.image as? NSData {    
    println("mybinary is not nil") // -> print "mybinary is not nil"
} else {
    println("mybinary is nil")
}
```

The `as? NSData`will cast `mybinary` if possible. If it is nil this will return nil instead of the optional type.

Comment: I added "?" in my @NSManaged var image: NSData?, then "if let imageBinary = self.selectedPost!.attachment?.image as NSData?" works. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to check with `!=nil`

As it stand, the value of `myBinary` is an optional.  You need to check its contents.